# Is there a comprehensive APA style manual available online?

Tags: apa

I am new to APA style and have noticed that web search results for specific APA style questions (e.g. "apa style p-values") tend to yield results from Q/A sites or of people's personal blogs summarizing the style, rather than any official-looking, fully-specified specification. Does an official specification exist? Is it available online?

[Clarification: I mean is it legitimately available online, in a web format. A google search for "apa manual pdf" turns up some PDFs where someone scanned in every page of the manual...better than nothing but not optimal.]

Comment: Did you try searching for "APA style guide"? When I do that search the top result is: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/01/ Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Purdue OWL doesn't have the complete specifications, especially not when it comes to reporting statistics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

The [APA Manual](http://www.apastyle.org/manual/) is published in print only. You will find it in any big library, or you can buy it (for $29.95), if you work in that style on a regular basis.

There are summaries of important rules available online from the teachers who made them for their students (usually you recognize them by a university URL), and there is the [Purdue Online Writing Lab](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/section/2/10/). But as I have learned in years of writing in APA style, there is nothing that replaces the original in scope and detail. Buying it is money well invested.

Specialist questions that are not answered by the manual can be asked on the official [APA Style Blog](http://blog.apastyle.org/).